Added xrextras-pwa-installer to a-scene and got [RuntimeError] XR caught an error; stopping. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: installPromptShown
I am working with the 8thwall Cloud Editor and trying to add the xrextras-pwa-installer to the <a-scene> to support PWA. However, I am encountering the following error in the console:
I referred to 8th Wall's documentation.
[RuntimeError] XR caught an error; stopping. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: installPromptShown

The installPromptShown variable is not defined anywhere in the project, and this error occurs when xrextras-pwa-installer is loaded within a-scene. I am a plus member of 8thwall.
Error on Terminal
[engine] VPS Session Id 1570685c2d5e4c668c07a5f3b6a92d36
[RuntimeError] XR caught an error; stopping. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: installPromptShown
XR threw an exception ReferenceError: Can't find variable: installPromptShown

a-scene code
<a-scene
  popup-event // When the target is tapped, another screen is displayed
  landing-page
  vps-coaching-overlay // This project uses VPS
  xrextras-loading
  xrextras-runtime-error
  xrextras-gesture-detector
**  xrextras-pwa-installer**
  renderer="colorManagement: true"
  xrweb="enableVps: true; allowedDevices: any">

Could someone help me resolve this error?
This is my head.html
<meta name="8thwall:renderer" content="aframe:1.5.0">
<meta name="8thwall:package" content="@8thwall.xrextras">
<meta name="8thwall:package" content="@8thwall.landing-page">
<meta name="8thwall:package" content="@8thwall.coaching-overlay">
<meta name="8thwall:package" content="@react.react">
<meta name="8thwall:package" content="@react.react-dom">
<meta name="8thwall:package" content="@react.react-router-dom">

I changed the order of elements loaded in a-scene
the first loaded xrweb.
<a-scene
  xrweb="enableVps: true; allowedDevices: any"
  popup-event
  landing-page
  vps-coaching-overlay
  xrextras-loading
  xrextras-runtime-error
  xrextras-gesture-detector
  xrextras-pwa-installer
  renderer="colorManagement: true">

ccore:a-assets
cAsset loading timed out in %c color: orange color: inherit color: orange 3000 ms
17:44:32
▼ Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.constructor')
at x 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
at callUpdateHandler 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
at updateProperties 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
at updateComponent 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
at updateComponents 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
at (anonymous) 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
at (anonymous) 8frame-1.5.0.min.js
[engine] VPS Session Id 1570685c2d5e4c668c07a5f3b6a92d36
[RuntimeError] XR caught an error; stopping. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: installPromptShown
.
.
.

